# Is it possible to show views exposed filters in the facet current search block?

Tags: views, search

I have a facet search with Facet API, Search API, and a Solr backend with the Search API Views integration.  I am using the Current Search block (part of the Facet API module) to display the currently selected facet options.

However, I am also using Views, and I have two exposed filters with the autosubmit button on the page.  **The problem is that users can select one of the views exposed filters and it will not appear in the Current Search block, so it is not obvious to the user that the results are being further filtered.**

I am also using Facet API Pretty Paths, so I have a path that looks like this:

> myexample.com/s/n/1/b/2&items_per_page=8&jp=1&d=-

`n/1`  and `b/2` are facets, `&items_per_page=8` is the views pager, and `&jp=1` and `&d=-` are the views exposed filters.

My goal is to somehow make it clear to the user that Views exposed filters are affecting the results.  If it's possible to modify the Current Search block, I would like to do that, but if not, creating a separate block/ctools content type to notify the user that the exposed filters are applied would also be acceptable.

I'm not aware of any modules that show the applied exposed filters, so I'm thinking about writing code to check the query string for `jp` and `d` and then printing messages based on the results.  If there is an easier approach, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't add it into the Facet block, but you could just do the exposed filters in a block and put the exposed filters block near the Facet block (screenshot from the Advanced section of the View):

[image: Views exposed filters in block]

Comment: Actually I've already added the exposed filters as a block, but they are near the search facets.  The problem is that I also need to separately indicate that the exposed filters are being applied in or near the current search block.